# Redirect from old rewritten url to new rewritten url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in my vBulletin forum I switched to another form of URL Rewriting.

OLD URLs (examples):

```
miosito.it/forum/showthread.php/1552-GUIDA-HEIMDALL-Odin-per-Mac-OS-X-e-Linux
miosito.it/forum/showthread.php/255-Ciao-a-tutti
```

NEW URLs (examples):

```
miosito.it/forum/threads/1552-GUIDA-HEIMDALL-Odin-per-Mac-OS-X-e-Linux
miosito.it/forum/threads/255-Ciao-a-tutti
```

How I can redirect via .htaccess to the new link?

Comment: I tried with this: RewriteRule ^/(showthread.php)/(.*) /threads/$2  [R]  but doesn't work, I'm not really good with .htaccess

Comment: Is `/forum/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes, forum is a real directory.

Comment: Just an advice that showing your effort (even if not working) in question is always better to attract good answers and avoid down-votes ( I didn't downvote though ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/forum/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteRule ^showthread\.php/(.+)$ threads/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Just tried it but, it redirects me to http://www.mysite.it/threads/1552-GUIDA-HEIMDALL-Odin-per-Mac-OS-X-e-Linux (missing /forum/)

Comment: Ah there was minor mistake. I fixed it, try it now.